# How to use Flatlist inside the Modal?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, native-base

I tried to write the code below , However, i got a error,
`VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation because it can break windowing and other functionality - use another VirtualizedList-backed container instead.`

I figure out the problem is that `Flatlist` inside `Modal.Body`. Both of them implement the `ScrollViews` so it cause the error. How can I fix that?

```
      <Modal size="full">
        <Modal.Content minHeight="100%" flex="1">
            <Modal.Header>
               ...
            </Modal.Header>

            <Modal.Body px={0} py={1}>
                <Flex>
                    <FlatList
                      ...
                    />
                </Flex>
            </Modal.Body>

            <Modal.Footer borderTopWidth={0} justifyContent="center">
               ...
            </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal.Content>
    </Modal>
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, can you achieve it with { yourData.map((item) => <Component/>) }. This way you don't use a ScrollView and you can list your data. I haven't used native-base's Modal component, but react-native's own modal does not have this problem and they don't have a Body either.

Comment: you are right. do not use `Modal.Body` is the right answer

Answer (score 0):

You could make the nested `FlatList` horizontal with the `<FlatList horizontal />` prop